# Resources to start building my own mozilla

Tags: linux, browser, mozilla

I am trying to learn and build my own version of mozilla with customizations. But I have no idea where to start and how to proceed. Can someone enlighten me in the following aspects:

> 1.Where to clone the latest open source code for mozilla
>
> 2.Where to learn the browser architecture and file structure(For linux/Ubuntu) So that I can customize the codes and add my own custom
>   addons.
>
> 3.How to debug and build the browser for Linux.

I heard its purely HTML,CSS and javascript. I have a low level expertise in all of this but no idea where to put together all of these. Please enlighten me with any resources. Basically I need a kickstart. Googling didn't gives me any such basic tutorials. I hope someone here would have tried these things before :) Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very handy guide on how to build Mozilla Firefox on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Simple_Firefox_build). Here's an outline of the steps:

1. Install the build prerequisite for Linux as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Simple_Firefox_build/Linux_and_MacOS_build_preparation) - `wget -q https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/raw-file/default/python/mozboot/bin/bootstrap.py -O bootstrap.py && python bootstrap.py`
2. Clone the repository locally using mercurial - `hg clone https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central`
3. Change the current working directory to `mozilla-central` and then issue the `./mach build` command. This will produce a vanilla version of Firefox, unbranded (aka *developer build*).
4. Once building is complete, you can run your copy using `./mach build` or package it using `./mach package`.

In order to customize your build, you need to both change the code and the building options. The latter can be done by creating a `.mozconfig` file in the *mozilla-central* directory and adding the [desired build options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Configuring_Build_Options) there.

> Where to learn the browser architecture and file structure(For
>   linux/Ubuntu) So that I can customize the codes and add my own custom
>   addons.

To understand a bit more about the structure of the Firefox source code, you can have a look at [this nice overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Source_Code/Directory_structure). Basically, each top directory represents a component of the browser (e.g. dom, browser, toolkit, ...). Depending on what you need, you have to change the code in the related directory. When you're lost and trying to find what to change, [DXR](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/) can come to the rescue: it's the official Mozilla code search engine.

You mentioned addons: I'm not sure what's your objective, but if you just need to develop an addon, then you don't really need to build Firefox from scratch. There's a [lot of documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons) about how to create addons, if needed.

> How to debug and build the browser for Linux.

The first part of this answers explains how to build. In order to debug, once you've built Firefox, simply run it with the command `./mach run --debugger`. This will allow you to debug the C++ core of Firefox. However, for most of the front end code (which lives in *browser/**), that's not needed: you can simply run Firefox and use the [Browser Toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox).

Comment: Thanks for this. I mentioned addons because I wanted to add few addons to firefox as a default during building :)

Comment: I see! You could also check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Enterprise_deployment#Packaging_Extensions) to understand how to package and ship addons in a custom build. Please consider accepting the answer if it was helpful to you!